# R regex for extraction of complex string

Tags: regex, r

I have a messy set of strings as follows.

```
string <- c("GRP-14994/", "GRP-7056 GRP-7036/", "grp-24263(24263)/IRGC 28588", "GRP-15916 /IRGC-42176",
            "GRP-614-250B/", "( GRP 11432)/IRGC-14570", "Tourn", "GRPP256", "Purse", "GRP-14956 Origin:", "GRP 10537", "GRP-10096 Origin: ",
            "SGRP123", "GRP1234", "AC-30009 (GRPHANA)/", "AC-3060 GRP 536-143/Old AC", "RGRPfaa/23", "/-",
            "MGR:7251/", "1216-GR-567/", "X:1 Well KGRPh", "WabGRPvea(II)", "HR33(BGRP)", "Tensor",
            "Wald", "grp12312")
```

I am trying to extract all the instances where GRP followed by digits, which may be separated by space or "-".

My current attempt gives me the following result.

```
gsub("(.*)(\\b)(GRP)(-|\\s|)(\\d+)(\\/|\\b)(.*)","\\3\\5", string, ignore.case = T)
 [1] "GRP14994"            "GRP7056"             "grp24263"            "GRP15916"           
 [5] "GRP614"              "GRP11432"            "Tourn"               "GRPP256"            
 [9] "Purse"               "GRP14956"            "GRP10537"            "GRP10096"           
[13] "SGRP123"             "GRP1234"             "AC-30009 (GRPHANA)/" "GRP536"             
[17] "RGRPfaa/23"          "/-"                  "MGR:7251/"           "1216-GR-567/"       
[21] "X:1 Well KGRPh"      "WabGRPvea(II)"       "HR33(BGRP)"          "Tensor"             
[25] "Wald"                "grp12312"
```

But the desired output ris

```
out <-  c("GRP14994", "GRP7056 GRP7036", "grp24263", "GRP15916", "GRP614250", 
"GRP11432", "", "", "", "GRP14956", "GRP10537", "GRP10096", "", 
"GRP1234", "", "GRP536143", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"grp12312")

out
 [1] "GRP14994"        "GRP7056 GRP7036" "grp24263"        "GRP15916"        "GRP614250"       "GRP11432"       
 [7] ""                ""                ""                "GRP14956"        "GRP10537"        "GRP10096"       
[13] ""                "GRP1234"         ""                "GRP536143"       ""                ""               
[19] ""                ""                ""                ""                ""                ""               
[25] ""                "grp12312"
```

How to modify the regex to get the desired result?

Comment: The expected output you provided does not look correct. Would `GRP614` not be `GRP614250`? And `GRPP256`? It has two **P**s

Comment: if that is your input, and you are sure about the incoming data, you can force the string to begin with the given GRP string by starting your regexp with ^ without (.*) so that it will match all strings beginning with GRP

Comment: What about `GRPP256` ...

Comment: Your output is still not correct! You have a string of `GRP 536-143` which you have as `GRP536` in the output, but should be `GRP536143` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(string,"[Gg][rR][pP][-\\s]?\\d+"), function (x) { gsub("[-\\s]+(\\d)", "\\1", paste(x, collapse= " "),perl=T) }))
 [1] "GRP14994"        "GRP7056 GRP7036" "grp24263"       
 [4] "GRP15916"        "GRP614"          "GRP11432"       
 [7] ""                ""                ""               
[10] "GRP14956"        "GRP10537"        "GRP10096"       
[13] "GRP123"          "GRP1234"         ""               
[16] "GRP536"          ""                ""               
[19] ""                ""                ""               
[22] ""                ""                ""               
[25] ""                "grp12312"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern

```
(.*)(\\b)(GRP)(-|\\s|)(\\d+)(\\/|\\b)(.*)","\\3\\5
```

*Faults found in your pattern*

> **1**.You want to capture something like this `GRP-668-888`, but in your
>   pattern you provided an option for only a hyphen followed by a number
>   i.e `GRP-668`
>
> **2**. Since you aren't making use of other words then there is no need for
>   the greedy expression `(.*)` before and after your pattern. You can
>   just make use of `"` since it always comes before `GRP`
>
> **3**. Also there is no need for the word boundary `\\b` before `(GRP)`  in
>   your pattern.

These are the important ones i could detect for now.

You can as well try out this pattern below

```
gsub("(grp)[-\s]?(\d+)[-\s]?(\d+)","\\1\\2\\3", string, ignore.case = T)
```

**`grp:`** captures grp if its in the string

**`[-\s]?:`** captures a hyphen `-` or a space `\s` which can be optional

**`(\d+):`** captures one or more numbers

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gT9uU3/6)